# Do any Belgian banks offer "virtual" accounts/cards/investment systems/funds where I can put aside money for purchase budgeting?

Tags: savings, budget, belgium

In order to be fiscally responsible, I would like to put aside a number of small distinct amounts of my monthly salary for specific types of purchases. For example, currently I do my PC games budgeting by redeeming a small 20-25 EUR Steam gift card at the start of every month, though this has the issue that any games that aren't available on Steam aren't covered by this budget. It's also sometimes not as easy to actually stick to that budget considering I often get tempted into redeeming gift cards for yearly events like major sales or my birthday.

I also want to start putting some budget aside for larger purchases in the long-term future. For example, while I did buy a new 2000 EUR gaming computer about 18 months ago, I am already vaguely planning ahead when I intend to replace it, though the final budget and parts are obviously uncertain today. I'd like to start setting money aside for it though so that when the time comes I have a more fixed budget instead of what happened with that 2000 EUR computer where my original budget was around 1300 EUR...

In order to deal with both of these issues, I'd be interested to know if my current bank Belfius, or another Belgian bank has a way to put aside an accumulating amount of money in a sort of "virtual bank account", where it is considered part of the main bank account for purposes of taxation and interest payments, but it's not directly available for withdrawal or purchases through the main debit card.

My bank used to have something called "premarital saving" which was a system where you could save money every year and when you'd get married or you'd turn 30 you'd get the entire amount alongside a really high interest amount. I think the interest I got off that was double the money I put in myself. I was one of the last people who were allowed to do that though, and I don't know if something similar exists these days. I know there's things like obligations and bonds, but those aren't really what I'm after because AFAIK those are an upfront investment today of the full amount in return for getting the amount back later.

Comment: I don't know Belgan tax law, but why isn't a real account acceptable?

Comment: @keshlam Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't cost additional money to maintain. While most banks in Belgium do have a free debit account offering, it generally is too restrictive for purposes like this.